# How can I dock a div in IE 8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

you amazingly kind and intelligent people.  Consider the following HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="Panel1" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; top: 0;
        width: 259; background-color: #00FF00">
        <input type="button" style="position: absolute;
            left: 161; top: 30; width: 75; height: 25" tabindex="3"/>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm doing here is docking the div to the right hand side of the screen so that it extends from the top to the bottom.  This works perfectly in Google Chrome, but not in IE8.

I've uploaded the page here http://losthobbit.net/temp/testdoc.html  in order to make your life just a little bit easier.

Any idea as to how I can get this working in IE?

Thanks!

Comment: The [invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) with the [invalid CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)?

Comment: For some reason I did not notice this comment until someone pointed it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just add a valid doctype and your done ;)

Ex.:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: I gave that a shot... (see http://losthobbit.net/temp/doctype.html )... and now it doesn't work at all.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: <strike>your</strike> you're  - pet peeve of mine ;)

Comment: @Lost Hobbit -- the reason it doesn't work at all after adding the `strict` doctype is that the HTML and CSS are invalid, and `strict` doctype enforces validity. Fix the code, and this doctype will work. See @Quinten's comment for links to where to go to validate them. Alternatively, use a non-strict doctype like simply `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 0):

I must be losing it in my old age...

All I have to do is set the height to 100%.